# SQL Find Possible Matches by Name and Address

Tags: sql, search, stored-procedures, find, match

We have a SQL Server 2008 Database table of "Companies" consisting of Name, Address, City, State, Zip and Phone

Users go to our web form, submit their information, and we need to determine if they are in our database records, or a new company.

**Example Data**

[image]

I've written a SQL Stored Procedure that will check for matches by State/Zip, Name, Address, City/Phone.  Any hit by one of those 4 matches triggers a record to be returned.

Then, using VB.NET, I plan on assigning points based on what matches were hit.  For example, a Name match will be 20 points... but the State/Zip match might only be 5 or 10 points.

**Example SQL script**.

1. Obviously, I will be using parameters to take in the data points, instead of hard-coded.
2. You'll notice I'm cleansing the address to only be the numeric values... and the name to be alphas.

   ```
   WITH 

   Match_StateZip as (
       select ID
       from vwCompanies
       where State = 'IA' and ZipCode like '25885%'
   ),
   Match_Name as (
       select ID
       from vwCompanies
       where Name like 'Best%Service%Ever%'  /* Excluded Corp, Ltd, Inc, and non-alpha */
   ),
   Match_Address as (
       select ID
       from vwCompanies
       where AddressLine1 like '%0429%9%' /* Only Numeric Portion */
   ),
   Match_CityPhone as (    
       select ID
       from vwCompanies
       where   City like 'Fort%Lauderdale%' and MainPhone like '%658%' /* First 3 (not area code) */
   )


   select comp.ID, Name, MainPhone, AddressLine1, City, State, ZipCode, 
       m_sz.ID 'm_sz', m_n.ID 'm_n', m_a.ID 'm_a', m_cp.ID 'm_cp'
   from vwCompanies comp
   left join Match_StateZip m_sz   on comp.ID = m_sz.ID
   left join Match_Name m_n        on comp.ID = m_n.ID
   left join Match_Address m_a     on comp.ID = m_a.ID
   left join Match_CityPhone m_cp  on comp.ID = m_cp.ID

   where m_sz.ID != '' OR m_n.ID != '' OR m_a.ID != '' OR m_cp.ID != ''
   ```

**My Question**

Is there a much better way to write this SQL script to find better matches, and/or be more accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Our program does this exact same thing as far as the UI. If users want to locate a company, they may search on Name, Address, or phone number. It seems like you're in the right direction  with a point system. A bit creative that's for sure (creative is a good thing). My suggestion is if at all possible add a "Locate by" drop down box to the UI. That's how our program is and you won't have to add any complex logic like this. Company name defaults to the "Locate By" selection so the users don't have to choose anything if they want to search by name. When they do this, the SP as you would imagine is very simple and straightforward... Adding the user input to a wildcard search on company name. Same for locating by address, and phone.

Things get really crazy when you want to find an entry's nearest neighbor. For example, user inputs "Hihg Times" and you want to return "High Times". That's where I've used a point system like you describe.